# Can't access websites with .me domain

Tags: internet, domain

I can't seem to access sites that end in .me, like about.me or flavors.me

Every other website seems to work fine, but I just can't access those particular ones. I'm on Starbucks wifi, so I don't know if that has anything to do with this. I can access the sites from my phone of 3G, but not on the computer.

Comment: Try with another device on the same Wi-Fi or the same computer on another Wi-Fi.

Comment: check your DNS settings - If Starbucks allows you to override them, try 8.8.8.8 (Google) or 208.67.222.222 / 208.67.220.220 (Open DNS)

Comment: Your WWW browser gives an error message, or shows a page of some kind.  You're not asking a good question by not telling people this important information.

Answer (score 7):

This is an issue with AT&T WiFi Hotspots.

Apparently it's a known issue and AT&T requests that you tell the Starbuck's manager where you're experiencing the problem to get in touch with AT&T WiFi at 888-888-7520 and have them escalate ticket number 178973186.

Comment: I called this number and talked with a tech support rep (I've been having this problem for a while) and he basically said: we know, it's complicated, we probably can't fix it. The short fix is to edit your hosts file so you can access the hosts you want. Ugh. Seems like a ridiculous problem to have.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue as you are and it appears to be localized to the ISP that both Starbucks and Barnes and Noble uses. I can resolve my oc3.me domain even at the Starbucks using Google Internet a few miles away but the majority of the other Starbucks cannot. Based on what I can tell it looks like they use AT&T enterprise Internet services.

Please see the DIG results below:

---

```
mi6:~ JabuXm3$ dig ns oc3.me

; <<>> DiG 9.8.5-P1 <<>> ns oc3.me
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 3960
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;oc3.me.                IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
me.         604800  IN  SOA upgrade.me. root.nmd.sbx16904.sanantx.wayport.net. 1 604800 86400 2419200 604800

;; Query time: 9 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.5.1#53(192.168.5.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Jan 16 10:22:19 CST 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 105
```

---

I made some changes to my oc3.me DNS around early December as well and originally wrote it off as possibly a propagation issue, but then after a month of waiting patiently and being able to access my domain everywhere else it seems to be ISP problem at these stores...

I wish there was a way to get in contact with the ISP directly to fix the issue but I'm afraid that this is what you get when getting "free" wifi. :(